# React native - State won't update on navigation

Tags: react-native, navigation, react-navigation

I'm not sure if the title is informative enough, but I'll try explaining my need.

I have two stacks in my application. I have a floating component that appears everywhere in my app(No matter in which stack I am), that shows some items, and by clicking them it will navigate to a component that renders this item. The navigation code is:

```
navigation.navigate('Tabs', {
    screen: 'Home',
    params: { screen: 'Dish', params: { from: '', data: dish } },
})
```

Now the problem is, if I'm already inside the screen `Dish` that render this item, and then use the floating component to navigate to another item, my state isn't rerendering, and keeps its old values.

I've managed to solve this by changing the code to:

```
navigation.push('Dish', {from: '', data: dish})}
```

Which simply push the component into the stack, though it made another problem; If I'm in my second stack (not the Tab one), then this doesn't work and won't navigate me anywhere, which make sense..

I also managed to solve this by navigating to the `Tab` stack and then pushing my component like this:

```
navigation.navigate('Tabs', {screen:'Home'})
navigation.push('Dish', {from: '', data: dish})}
```

This works, though I'm not sure if this is good practice. I was wondering if this is the correct way of achieving what I want.. Maybe I should just make my component rerender so the state changes? I tried to include as little code as I could, if anything else is needed I'll add it..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have any kind of listener or hook inside Dish screen that watches for state changes?

Comment: No I don't.. I still don't understand them that good so I'm carefull with using them, that's one of the reasons I asked the question to know if I should use a hook here or this is good enough solution @IanVasco

Comment: The usual problem with navigation is that the screen keeps mounted, so it works by the first time. Usually, we might need to add the Focus hook from react-navigation or use a useEffect hook to watch for navigation params changes

Answer (score 0):

It's not the best solution but you can use this :

```
     componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.route.params !== prevProps.route.params) {
           //What you want to do      

     }
```

Using the DidUpdate only when the params change to avoid infinite loop.

Or looking after listener.